# Inject Number in Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this scope which retrieves a name based on the array number (where the 3 is) and this works.

```
$scope.categoryList[3].name
```

Now I am trying to replace that number with a variable that comes in from a function so I get a different name each time the function is called. The Variable is obviously numeric. In theory should work but I know I am missing something...

```
$scope.getUserGroup = function(userGroup) {
    console.log($scope.categoryList[userGroup].name);
}
```

Comment: Are you encountering any error message?

Comment: Would you mind creating plnkr/fiddle for same ?

Comment: We have no way to evaluate what your problem is. Please read [mcve]

Comment: @bvoleti yes I am getting cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/fHPjNokp0lJb875HOelN

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('mainapp', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.categoryList = [{
    name: "toto"
  }, {
    name: "tete"
  }];
  $scope.getUserGroup = function(userGroup) {
    $scope.result = $scope.categoryList[userGroup].name;
  }

}]);
```

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="mainapp">
  {{result}}
  <br>
  <button ng-click="getUserGroup(1)">clic</button>
</body>
```